# Replacement of a combination of parameters with a single parameter

Tags: replacement

Suppose we have the equation 1+u/(L $\omega$) and we want to replace L $\omega$ / u with Da such that this yields the new equation 1+1/Da.

Is Mathematica able to do that?
`FullSimplify[1 + u/(L ω), Da == ω L/u]]` or `Assuming[{u, ω} ∈ PositiveReals, FullSimplify[1 + u/(L ω), Da == ω L/u]]` does not the trick. (It essentially only works when not replacing a division, i.e. for instance `FullSimplify[1 + u/(L ω), Da1 == ω L]]`.)

Comment: `1 + u/(L ω) /. Solve[Da == ω L/u, L]` ? Solving for any parameter will do.

Comment: @Syed thank you, that is what I was searching for. The approach wasn't apparent to me beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

MMA does pattern matching purely structurally. Look at the full form of the following expressions:

```
u/(L ω)  // FullForm

Times[Power[L,-1],u,Power[ω,-1]]
```

and:

```
(ω L/u) // FullForm

Times[L,Power[u,-1],ω]
```

You see that the structure is different. To get the same structure you need 1/(ω L/u) or u/(ω L):

```
u/(L ω)  // FullForm

Times[Power[L,-1],u,Power[ω,-1]]
```

With this you can now replace like:

```
1 + u/(L ω)  /.  u/(ω L) -> 1/Da

1 + 1/Da
```

Comment: I want Mathematica to handle this structuring automatically; that's why @Syed  comment is a suitable solution for me.